# (PHP) Web form inserting blank values into the database! Error - array(1) { [“g-recaptcha-response”]=> string(484)-

Tags: php, curl, pdo

When sending information from my web form, it inserts blank values into the database. The auto increments on the ID work fine. When performing an Var Dump $_POST, I get this response:

```
array(1) { ["g-recaptcha-response"]=> string(484) + random letters and numbers
```

I am trying to pass three values into my database from the user. First Name. Last Name and Email. It checks the values on my web site and looks like the Google Recaptcha V2 is working the way it was intended. I think it has something to do with the Recaptcha PHP script is not passing it to my insert PHP script.

Any Ideas? Thanks for taking the time to help me out.

PHP:

```
<?php
function post_captcha($user_response) {
    $fields_string = '';
    $fields = array(
        'secret' => '',
        'response' => $user_response
    );
    foreach($fields as $key=>$value)
    $fields_string .= $key . '=' . $value . '&';
    $fields_string = rtrim($fields_string, '&');

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, count($fields));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields_string);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, True);

    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    return json_decode($result, true);
}

// Call the function post_captcha
$res = post_captcha($_POST['g-recaptcha-response']);

if (!$res['success']) {
    // What happens when the CAPTCHA wasn't checked
    echo '<p>Please Check the Security CAPTCHA Box.</p><br>';
} else {
    // If CAPTCHA is successfully completed...
    // Paste mail function or whatever else you want to happen here!



$dbhost = "localhost";
$dbname = "";
$dbusername = "";
$dbpassword = "";


try {
$link = new PDO("mysql:host=$dbhost;dbname=$dbname", $dbusername, $dbpassword);
$link->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION); 

$statement = $link->prepare("INSERT INTO MailV2(Fname, Lname, Email) VALUES(:Fname, :Lname, :Email)");

$FirstName = $_POST['Fname'];
$LastName = $_POST['Lname'];
$Email = $_POST['Email'];

$statement->execute(array(
":Fname" => "$FirstName",
":Lname" => "$LastName",
":Email" => "$Email"));
 // Echo Successful attempt
        echo "<p Data added to database.</p></br></br>";

    }
    catch (PDOException $e) {
        echo "Error: " . $e->getMessage();
    }
      }
?>
```

HTML:

```
<article class="contact-form">
    <form action="" method="POST">
        <div class="col-md-5 col-md-offset-1 contact-form-left">
            <input class="Fname" type="text" placeholder="FIRST NAME*">
            <input class="Lname" type="text" placeholder="LAST NAME*">
            <input class="Email" type="email" placeholder="EMAIL*">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-5 contact-form-right text-right">
            <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey=""></div>
            <br>
            <input type="submit" class="submit-btn" value="Subscribe"> 
        </div>
    </form>
</article>
```

Comment: did you checked print_r($_POST); ?

Comment: Using print_r($_POST);   -  I received this:     Array ( [g-recaptcha-response] => 03AEHxwuzN5eoLVChWfmmDhkBA7OBARwrl2udu6lNEVr1_69X6VrOLDsOucoR2hHf1F2x3DRv923y1oQkXcWmtjLt3n_ScCYUtsKB-wrBSxC6ceAMqDqjbsp3hBJuFcZky7e-Cdyc5EnJwJ5auP4svKtdOs9wkFMi33mTlFWoqOJUTDRfGCobrnjvwiOPRMGMLkjbB5WazR71vl0UPPNOYuc4Rq2Y1NeJWwXG8iwU990sRbc7F8eDxMMnRORzlSzEcfV6mDiKgaFANpEPI29C7bS4KiiVPdcqePvLb8xjof0X45NCld3_fkM5ttk0b9AaRqRLcGxv8tduY )

Comment: can you include the html form?

Comment: removed the `mysqli` tag your code have no `mysqli` functions

Comment: I just figured it out.  Thanks for the help, I have been so fixed on my PHP coding that I didn't realize that the classes need to change to name.  Duh

Comment: Question, Is my code MYSQL?or PDO?  I wanted to write this in PDO but I am not sure as I want to stay away from  MYSQL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your html form, the name and email fields don't have a name attribute so they aren't included in the response.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks KAF, I just realize that and fix it.  I was so fixed on my php, I didn't notice it until I posted it here.  It always the simple things.

Fixed HTML:

```
<article class="contact-form">
    <form action="" method="POST">
        <div class="col-md-5 col-md-offset-1 contact-form-left">
            <input name="Fname" type="text" placeholder="FIRST NAME*">
            <input name="Lname" type="text" placeholder="LAST NAME*">
            <input name="Email" type="email" placeholder="EMAIL*">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-5 contact-form-right text-right">
            <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey=""></div>
            <br>
            <input type="submit" class="submit-btn" value="Subscribe"> 
        </div>
    </form>
</article>
```

Comment: Thanks K.A.F.   I would Up Vote you and check the answer but it wont let me. So Thank You!